# How to Copy checked checkbox from one table to another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two table where Table 1 is master table for table 2. If I Click addnew button than a new row will added in both table 1 and table 2 and Whatever employee name i will write it will be copied in table 2 same time. I want to Copy checked input checkbox also from table 1 to table2.I have added my code please help.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert66").click(function() {
    $(".copySubName tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName"> </td></td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td></tr>')
    $("#tableboth tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr>')
  });
  $('.copySubName').on('input', '.EmpName', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('table').find('input').index(this);
    //for second table
    $('#tableboth').find('.EmpName').eq(index).val($(this).val())
    //for 3rd table
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="table66" class="table table-bordered table-hover copySubName">
      <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insert66"></input>
      <thead>

        <th>Employee Name</th>
         <th> is mandatory</th>

      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName">
          </td>
<td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub">
              </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>



    <div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualSalSection">
      <div class="portlet-body individual individualSalSectionSub">
        Table2:
        <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual">

          <thead>
            <th>Employee</th>
            <th> Marks</th>
            <th> is mandatory</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years">
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="mandatorySub">
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/ Please utilize google.

Comment: ^-- not only that, but please pay attention to the id's too. You are making duplicate id's when copying over. the `id` attribute should be unique.

Comment: can you help me with some working fiddle ?

Comment: add new is not adding checkbox in table 1 is it a bug ?

Comment: now check . i have solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mandatorySub` as a class rather than multiple ids everywhere. The usage of ids are supposed to be unique inside a document.

What you should aim for is to fire an event on `change` of status of your checkboxes, and make the other checkboxes checked/unchecked accordingly.

Refer code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert66").click(function() {
    $(".copySubName tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName"> </td></td> <td> <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub"> </td></tr>')
    $("#tableboth tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub"> </td> </tr>')
  });
  $('.copySubName').on('input', '.EmpName', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('table').find('input').index(this);
    //for second table
    $('#tableboth').find('.EmpName').eq(index).val($(this).val())
    //for 3rd table
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".mandatorySub", function() {
    var checkboxIndex = $(this).closest('table').find('input[type="checkbox"]').index(this)
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#tableboth').find('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(checkboxIndex).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $('#tableboth').find('input[type="checkbox"]').eq(checkboxIndex).prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="table66" class="table table-bordered table-hover copySubName">
  <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insert66" />
  <thead>

    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th> is mandatory</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualSalSection">
  <div class="portlet-body individual individualSalSectionSub">
    Table2:
    <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual">

      <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th> Marks</th>
        <th> is mandatory</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working only for 1st row only. if i click on addnew than its not working on new rows. Please check

Comment: That was because your checkboxes were dynamic. Added `event delegation` to handle dynamic event handling. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change id="mandatorySub" to class="mandatorySub1" and class="mandatorySub2"

I had updated your code may be this will help you if i understand you correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#insert66").click(function() {
    $(".copySubName tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName"> </td><td><input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub1"></td></tr>')
    $("#tableboth tbody").append('<tr> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName"> </td> <td> <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years"> </td> <td> <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub2"> </td> </tr>')
  });
  $('.copySubName').on('input', '.EmpName', function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('table').find('input').index(this);
    //for second table
    $('#tableboth').find('.EmpName').eq(index).val($(this).val())
    //for 3rd table
  });
  $('body').on('click','.mandatorySub1',function(){
     $('input.mandatorySub2').eq($("input.mandatorySub1").index( this )).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="table66" class="table table-bordered table-hover copySubName">
  <input type="button" class="btn green" value="Add New+" id="insert66"></input>
  <thead>

    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th> is mandatory</th>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" name="EmpName">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub1">
      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<div class="portlet light portlet-fit box individual individualSalSection">
  <div class="portlet-body individual individualSalSectionSub">
    Table2:
    <table id="tableboth" class="arrSubjects table table-striped table-hover arrSubjects individual">

      <thead>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th> Marks</th>
        <th> is mandatory</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control EmpName" disabled="true" name="EmpName">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control years allownumericwithoutdecimal" maxlength="3" name="years">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="mandatorySub2">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```